# how to use grouping value in aggregation function in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have dataframe consisting of two columns: first one is for groups names, and second is for values that are related to given group (so one group can have multiple values).
I'd like to concatenate values to keep just one entry for each group and also add some extra info.

```
grouped = df.groupby('group_name').agg(lambda x: 'some additional info:\n{}'.format('\n'.join(x)))
```

sample row of grouped looks like this:

```
Citrus    "some additional info\nLemon\nOrange\nGrapefruit"
```

Is there some elegant way to include group_name in such aggregation so result would be like the one shown below?

```
Citrus    "some additional info\nCitrus\nLemon\nOrange\nGrapefruit"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
  group_name         col
0     Citrus       Lemon
1     Citrus      Orange
2     Citrus  Grapefruit
```

Because [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) method working with each column separately is possible convert column to index and select index value:

```
f = lambda x: 'some additional info:\n{}\n{}'.format(x.index[0], '\n'.join(x))
grouped = df.set_index('group_name').groupby('group_name')['col'].agg(f)
print (grouped)
group_name
Citrus    some additional info:\nCitrus\nLemon\nOrange\n...
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Or is possible use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
f = lambda x: 'some additional info:\n{}\n{}'.format(x.name, '\n'.join(x['col']))
grouped = df.groupby('group_name').apply(f)
print (grouped)
group_name
Citrus    some additional info:\nCitrus\nLemon\nOrange\n...
dtype: object
```